# Unable to merge multiple streams into one

Tags: scala

I am trying to merge content of multiple files into single file and to test my code,

I have 3 files in my test dir -
file1.txt : this
file2.txt : is
file3.txt : test

and here is the code to combine all 3 files as stream and write to single "out.txt" file.
but this code only write content of one file to "out.txt", why ?

**

```
import java.io.{File, FileInputStream, InputStream, SequenceInputStream}
  import scala.collection.JavaConverters.asJavaEnumeration
  def mergeInputStreams(files: Iterator[File]): InputStream = new SequenceInputStream(asJavaEnumeration(files.map(new FileInputStream(_))))
  val d = "/Users/pink/temp"
  val file = new File(d);
  //file.listFiles.iterator.foreach(println)
  val fss = mergeInputStreams(file.listFiles.toIterator)
  val outfile = new File("/Users/pink/tmp/out.txt")
  val os = new FileOutputStream(outfile)
  try {
    while (fss.available()>0) {
      os.write(fss.read())
    }
  } finally {
    fss.close()
    os.close()
  }
```

**

I expect the above code should produce one file with following content -
out.txt:
this is test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior happens because `fss.available() > 0` is a wrong check for such a task. The JavaDoc for [InputStream.available()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()) says (emphasis is mine)

> Returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream ***without blocking*** by the next invocation of a method for this input stream.

The fact that `fss.available() > 0` guarantees that the stream is not finished but it is not true in the reverse direction: `fss.available()` might be `0` but you might still be able to read more data. This is potentially true even for file-based `InputStream`s. For example, assume that the file is actually located on a different server mounted using some network file system. In such case an implementation of `available` that returns the number of bytes cached on the client side is a reasonable implementation of the interface because getting more data does require a blocking request over the network.

If you read the JavaDoc for [SequenceInputStream.available()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/SequenceInputStream.html#available()) you may see

> ...
>   This method simply calls `available` of the current underlying input stream and returns the result.

And this is probably the only sane implementation of the interface contract: generally you can't in a non-blocking way distinguish between cases when `is.available() == 0` because the end was reached and when just more waiting or a blocking operation is needed to get more data.

The intent of the `available` method is to be used for various optimizations, not as a check for the end of the stream. The only proper check for whether `InputStream` has reached the end is potentially blocking `read() == -1`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out issue with fss.available() > 0. I modified code using read() != -1 and it worked as expected.                                                                                                           var c = 0
  try {
    while ({
      c = fss.read()
      c != -1
    }) {
      os.write(c)
    }
  } finally {
    fss.close()
    os.close()
  }

Comment: @AKS, please note that although this is technically a correct way, copying data 1 byte at a time is awfully inefficient. If you are going to handle big files, you should consider using one of the other two `read` methods that use a buffer `byte[]` array or even the `java.nio` package (take a look at [Pipe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Pipe.html)).

Answer (score 0):

`mergeInputStreams` is working correctly, but the while loop for writing the `InputStream` to the `FileOutputStream` isn't getting all of the content. @SergGr's answer very clearly states why this is happening. By replacing the read-write while loop with the [IOUtils](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.6) copy method everything gets written to the file, but in the wrong order. The order of the output is determined by this line of code:

```
file.listFiles.toIterator
```

once we sort the input files, we get this in out.txt:

```
this
is
test
```

Here's the code that does this:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters.asJavaEnumeration
import java.io.{File, FileInputStream, InputStream, FileOutputStream, SequenceInputStream, IOException}
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

object Example1 {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    def mergeInputStreams(files: Iterator[File]): InputStream = 
        new SequenceInputStream(asJavaEnumeration(files.map(new FileInputStream(_))))
    val d = "/Users/pink/temp"
    val file = new File(d)
    val fss = mergeInputStreams(file.listFiles.toList.sorted.toIterator)
    val os = new FileOutputStream(new File("/Users/pink/tmp/out.txt"))
    try {
      IOUtils.copy(fss, os)
    }
    catch {
      case e: IOException => println(s"IO exception: $e.getMessage")
    }
  }
}
```

This solution definitely works, but we're using a lot of Java code where side-effects happen without our type system knowing. Because of that we have to be careful to catch exceptions and place IO operations exactly where we want them.

A more functional way to write this would be with [fs2 Streams](https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2#about-the-library). Here's the example from their [readme file](https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2#about-the-library) modified to match what your code is doing:

```
import cats.effect.{ExitCode, IO, IOApp, Resource}
import cats.implicits._
import fs2.{io, text, Stream}
import java.nio.file.Paths
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

object Example2 extends IOApp {
  private val blockingExecutionContext =
        Resource.make(IO(ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2))))(ec => IO(ec.shutdown()))

  val converter: Stream[IO, Unit] = Stream.resource(blockingExecutionContext).flatMap { blockingEC =>

    val f1 = io.file.readAll[IO](Paths.get("/Users/pink/temp/file1.txt"), blockingEC, 4096)
    val f2 = io.file.readAll[IO](Paths.get("/Users/pink/temp/file2.txt"), blockingEC, 4096)
    val f3 = io.file.readAll[IO](Paths.get("/Users/pink/temp/file3.txt"), blockingEC, 4096)

    (f2 merge f3 merge f1)
      .through(text.utf8Decode)
      .through(text.lines)
      .intersperse("\n")
      .through(text.utf8Encode)
      .through(io.file.writeAll(Paths.get("/Users/pink/tmp/out.txt"), blockingEC))
  }

  def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] =
    converter.compile.drain.as(ExitCode.Success)
}
```

No IO operations happen until run is called, and all exceptions are maintained inside the IO type so we don't have to worry about catching throughout our code.